# Retrive text inside a nested span?

Tags: html, jquery, css

I have the following dynamic HTML, and I would like to change the color of the  based on text inside the last span element, in that case, an "OK".

```
<div class="data">
    <div class="fundoDiv">
        <section>
            <header class="textoHeader">Risk</header>
        </section>
    <span id="b74ac226bea04e10a80e25bbf7e529a3" style="font-family:'Arial';font-size:37px;">
<span id="f95f8aba-1b60-4174-9354-8945634b6179" viewid="f95f8aba-1b60-4174-9354-8945634b6179" class="EmbeddedMiniatureVisualization" sf-busy="false" style="position: relative; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; border: 0px; overflow: hidden;">
<span style="color: rgb(97, 100, 107); text-align: left;">OK</span></span></span>
</div>
```

I have tried some different approaches, but none of them has given me the correct text, so the  color was not changed. In fact, the console.log(text) command has no output. Below is the jQuery I'm using for that.

```
$(".fundoDiv span.EmbeddedMiniatureVisualization:last-child").each(function() {
    var text = $(this).text()
    console.log(text)
   if (text = 'OK') {
      $('div.fundoDiv').css("background-color", "green");
    } else {
      $('div.fundoDiv').css("background-color","red");
    }
});
```

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Marcio

Comment: one query: `span` with the class `EmbeddedMiniatureVisualization` will have only one child `span` inside it every time? or it can have multiple child `spans`?

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to trim your text to remove white spaces and compare instead of an assignment:

```js
$(".fundoDiv span.EmbeddedMiniatureVisualization:last-child").each(function() {
    var text = $(this).text().trim();
    console.log(text)
   if (text === 'OK') {
      $('div.fundoDiv').css("background-color", "green");
    } else {
      $('div.fundoDiv').css("background-color","red");
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="data">
    <div class="fundoDiv">
        <section>
            <header class="textoHeader">Risk</header>
        </section>
    <span id="b74ac226bea04e10a80e25bbf7e529a3" style="font-family:'Arial';font-size:37px;">
<span id="f95f8aba-1b60-4174-9354-8945634b6179" viewid="f95f8aba-1b60-4174-9354-8945634b6179" class="EmbeddedMiniatureVisualization" sf-busy="false" style="position: relative; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; border: 0px; overflow: hidden;">
<span style="color: rgb(97, 100, 107); text-align: left;">OK</span></span></span>
</div>
```

Comment: I guess you need to add `.trim()` to `$(this).text()`

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen done before reading your comment, but thanks

Comment: Thank you guys, but didn't work, and console output still empty. I forgot to mention that I have six DIVs that has the same fundoDiv class, and I would like to style each one based on the text.

Comment: @MarcioLino then we need the full code, please prepare a working snippet in the question, not just paste the code

Answer (score 0):

Use `$(".fundoDiv span.EmbeddedMiniatureVisualization:last-child").text().trim()`

```js
$(".fundoDiv span.EmbeddedMiniatureVisualization:last-child").each(function() {
    var text = $(".fundoDiv span.EmbeddedMiniatureVisualization:last-child").text().trim();
    console.log("{"+text+"}");
    if (text == 'OK') {
      $('div.fundoDiv').css("background-color", "green");
    } else {
      $('div.fundoDiv').css("background-color","red");
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="data">
    <div class="fundoDiv">
        <section>
            <header class="textoHeader">Risk</header>
        </section>
    <span id="b74ac226bea04e10a80e25bbf7e529a3" style="font-family:'Arial';font-size:37px;">
<span id="f95f8aba-1b60-4174-9354-8945634b6179" viewid="f95f8aba-1b60-4174-9354-8945634b6179" class="EmbeddedMiniatureVisualization" sf-busy="false" style="position: relative; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; border: 0px; overflow: hidden;">
<span style="color: rgb(97, 100, 107); text-align: left;">OKf</span></span></span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Inside `if` You are not comparing, you are doing an assignment so fix that. (`=` is assignment and `==` or `===` used for comparison)
2. Trim the text so that in case any starting/trailing space is there then they will get neglected while comparison.
3. You need to use `.closest()` as well to get the corresponding `fundoDiv` div after the comparison becomes successful or fails. (because you are looping over the span inside `fundoDiv` not on the `fundoDiv` itself so `$(this)` will reflect `<span>` actually)

Working snippet:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $(".fundoDiv span.EmbeddedMiniatureVisualization:last-child").each(function() {
    var text = $(this).find('span').text().trim();
    if (text === 'OK') {
      $(this).closest('.fundoDiv').css("background-color", "green");
    } else {
      $(this).closest('.fundoDiv').css("background-color", "red");
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.fundoDiv{
  margin-bottom : 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="data">
  <div class="fundoDiv">
    <section>
      <header class="textoHeader">Risk</header>
    </section>
    <span id="b74ac226bea04e10a80e25bbf7e529a3" style="font-family:'Arial';font-size:37px;">
<span id="f95f8aba-1b60-4174-9354-8945634b6179" viewid="f95f8aba-1b60-4174-9354-8945634b6179" class="EmbeddedMiniatureVisualization" sf-busy="false" style="position: relative; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; border: 0px; overflow: hidden;">
<span style="color: rgb(97, 100, 107); text-align: left;">OK</span></span>
    </span>
  </div>

  <div class="fundoDiv">
    <section>
      <header class="textoHeader">Risk</header>
    </section>
    <span id="b74ac226bea04e10a80e25bbf7e529a3" style="font-family:'Arial';font-size:37px;">
<span id="f95f8aba-1b60-4174-9354-8945634b6179" viewid="f95f8aba-1b60-4174-9354-8945634b6179" class="EmbeddedMiniatureVisualization" sf-busy="false" style="position: relative; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; border: 0px; overflow: hidden;">
<span style="color: rgb(97, 100, 107); text-align: left;">Not OK</span></span>
    </span>
  </div>
  
  <div class="fundoDiv">
    <section>
      <header class="textoHeader">Risk</header>
    </section>
    <span id="b74ac226bea04e10a80e25bbf7e529a3" style="font-family:'Arial';font-size:37px;">
<span id="f95f8aba-1b60-4174-9354-8945634b6179" viewid="f95f8aba-1b60-4174-9354-8945634b6179" class="EmbeddedMiniatureVisualization" sf-busy="false" style="position: relative; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; border: 0px; overflow: hidden;">
<span style="color: rgb(97, 100, 107); text-align: left;">OK</span></span>
    </span>
  </div>
</div>
```

**In case your span with the class** `EmbeddedMiniatureVisualization` contains multiple spans, and you want to search and match each of them then do like below:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $(".fundoDiv span.EmbeddedMiniatureVisualization:last-child").each(function() {
    var obj = $(this);
    var istextFound = false;
    obj.find('span').each(function() {
      if ($(this).text().trim() == 'OK') {
        istextFound = true;
        return;
      }
    });
    if (istextFound) {
      obj.closest('.fundoDiv').css("background-color", "green");
    } else {
      obj.closest('.fundoDiv').css("background-color", "red");
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.fundoDiv{
  margin-bottom : 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="data">
  <div class="fundoDiv">
    <section>
      <header class="textoHeader">Risk</header>
    </section>
    <span id="b74ac226bea04e10a80e25bbf7e529a3" style="font-family:'Arial';font-size:37px;">
<span id="f95f8aba-1b60-4174-9354-8945634b6179" viewid="f95f8aba-1b60-4174-9354-8945634b6179" class="EmbeddedMiniatureVisualization" sf-busy="false" style="position: relative; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; border: 0px; overflow: hidden;">
    <span style="color: rgb(97, 100, 107); text-align: left;">OK</span>
    <span style="color: rgb(97, 100, 107); text-align: left;">Not OK</span>
    </span>
  </div>

  <div class="fundoDiv">
    <section>
      <header class="textoHeader">Risk</header>
    </section>
    <span id="b74ac226bea04e10a80e25bbf7e529a3" style="font-family:'Arial';font-size:37px;">
<span id="f95f8aba-1b60-4174-9354-8945634b6179" viewid="f95f8aba-1b60-4174-9354-8945634b6179" class="EmbeddedMiniatureVisualization" sf-busy="false" style="position: relative; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; border: 0px; overflow: hidden;">
<span style="color: rgb(97, 100, 107); text-align: left;">Not OK</span>
    <span style="color: rgb(97, 100, 107); text-align: left;">Not OK</span>
    </span>
  </div>

  <div class="fundoDiv">
    <section>
      <header class="textoHeader">Risk</header>
    </section>
    <span id="b74ac226bea04e10a80e25bbf7e529a3" style="font-family:'Arial';font-size:37px;">
<span id="f95f8aba-1b60-4174-9354-8945634b6179" viewid="f95f8aba-1b60-4174-9354-8945634b6179" class="EmbeddedMiniatureVisualization" sf-busy="false" style="position: relative; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; border: 0px; overflow: hidden;">
<span style="color: rgb(97, 100, 107); text-align: left;">OK</span>
    <span style="color: rgb(97, 100, 107); text-align: left;">Not OK</span>
    </span>
  </div>
</div>
```